# Proof of this logarithm exercise

Tags: functions, logarithms

How can I proof that this function:

$f(x, y) = - y \log(x) - (1 - y) \log(1 - x)$

is the same as this function:

$g(x, y) = - \log(y x + (1 - y) (1 - x))$

being $y = \{0,1\}$ ?

(explanation step by step is needed)

Comment: I was curious to know if I have a function defined in two parts (for y = 0 and y = 1), which is the best way to define it in one formula, and why they are the same separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just try $y=0,1$:

$y=0:$
$$f=-\log(1-x)$$
$$g=-\log(1-x)$$

$y=1:$
$$f=-\log(x)$$
$$g=-\log(x)$$

Comment: Could I see any decomposition of f(x,y) that will be the same as g(x,y) without doing separately?

Comment: No, they are not equal for arbitrary $y$.

Answer (score 0):

You need to show $f(x,0) = g(x,0)$ and $f(x,1) = g(x,1)$ because $y = 0$ or $1$. We have $f(x,0) = -\log(1-x) = g(x,0)$, and $f(x,1) = -\log x = g(x,1)$. Thus you are done.

Comment: Could I see any decomposition of f(x,y) that will be the same as g(x,y) without doing separately?